# contentEditable field to maintain newlines upon database entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, newline, contenteditable

I have a div with the attribute contentEditable set.

This allows me to have a free-form editable textarea, without the need for any form input fields: http://jsfiddle.net/M8wx9/8/

However, when I create a couple of new lines and click save button, I grab the content with the `.text()` method which goes on to remove the line feeds I just entered. I need to maintain the newline characters if at all possible and store the content as plain text in the database.

I could store the HTML directly to the database by using `.html()` instead of `.text()` but I don't like that idea as I may need to extract this data as plain text in the future. Furthermore, pressing enter in Firefox breaks new lines with `<br>`, Chrome and Safari are breaking with `<div>...</div>` and Internet Explorer and Opera are using paragraphs `<p>...</p>` for new lines, so it doesn't sound very easy to be able to parse the html.

How can I preserve these line feeds and store the content as plain text in the database (Similar to the way a textarea does)?

Best Regards,
**ns**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

jQuery uses `textContent` on a `Node` to return the text value of an element, which will compress white space. If you want the line breaks to be maintained, you need to use `innerText` which means accessing the element directly rather than through jQuery.

From your jsfiddle:

```
console.log($(Comments)[0].innerText);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8wx9/10/

==== update:
As a caveat to this (as Tim Down has pointed out), using `innerText` will only work in webkit and microsoft browsers. If your application also supports Firefox, you will need to use regular expressions on the innerHTML in order to maintain line breaks. As an example:

```
$(Comments).html().trim()
.replace(/<br(\s*)\/*>/ig, '\n') // replace single line-breaks
.replace(/<[p|div]\s/ig, '\n$0') // add a line break before all div and p tags
.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");   // remove any remaining tags
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8wx9/12/

As mentioned in the comment, the previous is not working in Chrome. Here is a working solution:

```
$(Comments).html().trim()
.replace(/<br\s*\/*>/ig, '\n') 
.replace(/(<(p|div))/ig, '\n$1') 
.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8wx9/81/

Comment: Thank you so much. This has had me frustrated all morning. Now when I display the contents using PHP, I need to do the following to convert the line breaks back into `<br />` elements:
`$sanitized = htmlspecialchars($comments, ENT_QUOTES); 
$comments = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), array("<br />", "<br />"), $sanitized);`

Comment: PHP has a built-in method for adding line breaks: `nl2br` so you could do `$sanitized = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comments, ENT_QUOTES));` php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: `innerText` is not at all reliable, for several reasons: first, it is not supported in Firefox up to the current release at time of writing (17.0.1). Second, in Opera it is simply an alias for `textContent`. Third, there is no spec for it, so there's no telling how future browsers may implement it.

Comment: this works almost perfectly, I only found one bug:
Try writing something in the conteneditable div, then enter a few new lines and then again write something. After using the conversion mentioned above, there will be one new line less...

Comment: Unfortunately this regular expression doesn't work. Brackets instead of parenthesis, and for some unknown reason $0 doesn't reference matched string in Chrome. Following should work `$(Comments).html().trim().replace(/<br\s*\/*>/ig, '\n') .replace(/(<(p|div))/ig, '\n$1')  .replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");`

Comment: @MaximMazin +1. The accepted solution's regex is wrong.

Comment: Its been a few years, but i stumbled on this issue too, and the regex posted in the answer, and the one in the comments above result in an extra line when trying: <div>foo</div><p>line 1<br/> line2<br/><br/>line4\nline5</p>

Answer (score 1):

```
function readContentWithBreaks(elem){
  if(elem[0].innerText){
    return elem[0].innerText.replace(/\n/ig,"<br>");
  }else{
    return elem.html();
  }
}
```

Since webkit browsers support innerText I decided to detect for that swap the /n they add.
For Firefox it already gives the content with `<br>` so we can just take it as-is.

Comment: Maybe add some commentary so the bots don't nab you.