# Line break in editable div

Tags: html, nl2br

I have an editable div

```
<div id="content" contenteditable ="true">
</div>
```

I want the user to edit the div and save it into a file (so he can see it again when he come back to the web page). So what I do is basically sent a post request with the div content as a parameter. But the problem is that when the user add a line break, I cant find it in the query post. For example, if the user type this :

```
Hi there.
I'm Kevin.
What's up ?
```

I recieve :

```
Hi there.I'm Kevin.What's up.
```

The line break have bean trimed or deleted. If I try to show his message, I cant because I loose the line break..

I tried `nl2br` to show the message, and replaced the div by a `textarea` but doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764188/6158032

Comment: Possible duplicate of [contentEditable field to maintain newlines upon database entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762863/contenteditable-field-to-maintain-newlines-upon-database-entry)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pre tag. Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and **line breaks**.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp