# Paste fix for contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm running a script to sanitize pasted text in a div with contenteditable.

It's working pretty good, but in FF the line-breaks are removed if the text is copied to the same or between the divs.

Any solution for that?
If I paste text from a different source the line-breaks are intact. 
I'm also open to different solutions than the one below.

```js
// Paste fix for contenteditable
$(document).on('paste', '[contenteditable]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (window.clipboardData) {
        content = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');        
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var selObj = window.getSelection();
            var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
            selRange.deleteContents();                
            selRange.insertNode(document.createTextNode(content));
        }
    } else if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
        content = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, content);
    }        
});
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">Copy
and
paste
this
back in the same box or the one below. Where do they line-breaks go in FF?</div>
<div contenteditable="true">Copy
and
paste
this
back in the same box or the one above. Where do they line-breaks go FF?</div>
```

Comment: Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: you should use <br>

Comment: Why? It seems messy and also want to avoid html in the database/avoid adding/removing html.

Comment: I  can not see where is the issue, your example works just fine in the latest version of chrome

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher Yes, but try Firefox (at least on Mac)

Comment: Using Chrome console, i see that each line pasted is wrapped into a div, maybe to preserve line-breaks.

According to this, the whole solution should be revised as its result should be text only inside the contenteditable div.

I checked whats happening in firefox - confirmed what you say - and i think it is due to the way firefox copies the inner text of the contenteditable div.

I think i will try to aswer you tomorrow with something that ovverrides "copy for firefox to preserve newlines.

Comment: Here is some fiddle that should help understand what i would do.
Right now of course it can work only when the whole div is copied but gives you the idea of what is exactly the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/ofz4x7hp/18/ - to test with firefox.

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti Thank you! Looks promising. How can I get that applied to any length of selected text?

Comment: @SeaBass You're welcome. I had no time to work on the final answer that should exactly do that applied to the specific range of text selected. Anyway of course it will have to do with the selection API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). I will try the final answer tomorrow in the morning :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on FF 56 in Windows 10

Comment: @CertainPerformance Looks like one of those rare ones, but if it happens to me, chances are other people will experience it. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13762863/104380

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As promised, here is a working solution of such implementation discussed in question's comments.

While working with Selection and Range API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), i found that Range object has a toString() method and i thought to test it to see if newlines were trimmed here, before, or later.

Fortunatly, i found out that the toString() method in FF Range object doesn't trim out newlines.

According to that, here is my code and fiddle to override default copy function, overwriting (on copy event) what's inside the clipboard.

```js
$(document).on('copy', '[contenteditable]', function (e) {
  e = e.originalEvent;
  var selectedText = window.getSelection();
  console.log("original copied text\n--------\n", selectedText.toString());
  var range = selectedText.getRangeAt(0);
  var selectedTextReplacement = range.toString()
  console.log("replacement in clipboard\n--------\n", selectedTextReplacement);
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', selectedTextReplacement);
  e.preventDefault(); // default behaviour is to copy any selected text
});



// Paste fix for contenteditable
$(document).on('paste', '[contenteditable]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (window.clipboardData) {
        content = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');        
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var selObj = window.getSelection();
            var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
            selRange.deleteContents();                
            selRange.insertNode(document.createTextNode(content));
        }
    } else if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
        content = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, content);
    }        
});
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">Copy
and
paste
this
back in the same box or the one below. Where do they line-breaks go in FF?</div>
<div contenteditable="true">Copy
and
paste
this
back in the same box or the one above. Where do they line-breaks go FF?</div>
```

I also made rough test with edge and chrome, and that override "doesn't mess them up", so maybe you can keep it to have control over what they are doing when something is copied.

At the end of all, i still have a question that keeps yelling in my mind and it is:
Why use contenteditable div instead of textarea if you don't want html into your frontend element?

Comment: Giacomo, that's awesome! Thank you so much :) I've tried it in Firefox, Safari and Chrome and it turns out the way I want it to! That is a very good question. I wanted to use a textarea, but I needed it to fit the height of the text, which I needed javascript to do. With hundreds of textareas it got extremely slow and I started to look into divs instead, which are easy to change the height of based on content with just css. Thanks again!

Comment: Just one more thing. Can I get this to apply only when copying divs with contenteditable? `$(document).on('copy', '[contenteditable]', function (e) {` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @SeaBass That is cause jquery wraps the original event (pure js event) into (according to your code) `e.originalEvent` .
So after changing the listener to the jq one, we have to do `e = e.originalEvent` .
Here is a working fiddle with that edit with proof: http://jsfiddle.net/ofz4x7hp/55/ .
I will edit the answer too.

Comment: @SeaBass about the textarea thing, IMHO the path to increase performance in height resizing for textareas should be analyzed and leave this option (use contenteditable div forcing it to text only) as last chance (as it is meant for HTML content).
If you have hundreds of textarea in a single page, did you try to resize only those that user can see?
Or even better: resize a textarea when it has focus on it.
You're welcome!!

Comment: Thanks that worked! It's a scalable table like a google doc with custom fields so the user can potentially add unlimited number of fields, and there are two view modes: 1) the fields only expand when focued like you suggested 2) all fields are always expanded. 2 is what caused the sluggish performance. I did not try to only apply it to what is visible on the screen, but you mean that the JS would work as you scroll and apply it on the fly? I wonder if that would be slow too if the user starts scrolling and it has to load in the middle of it?

Comment: Okay, in that case its not good idea to resize each cell on scroll.
I think that if it is something like a big table can be contenteditable divs are ok, i did not imagine this specific context in the previous description.

Comment: Many thanks for your code. This is very useful because I was facing a similar problem : when I pasted some text from the same page into contenteditable, some line-breaks were impossible to delete ! Now it's fixed.

Comment: @Chrysotribax great! I believe there was still some tricky things in FF if I remember correctly.